# Grouping participants in SAS

Tags: sas, grouping

The file I'm using contains three groups of participants who fall into one of three weight categories: obese, normal weight, and successful weight loss maintainers. Thankfully their ID number correspond to the group they are in.   500s and 800s for obese, 600s for NW, and 700 for SWLMs.

This is the code I am using:

```
data dummy_2;
set dummy;
if ptID = 'group' then group=1;
if ptID = 102-545 or ID= 800-810 then group =0;
if ptID = 600-632 then group=1;
if ptID = 700-721 then group=2;
if ptID = 99999 or 99998 then group=.;
run;
```

the code itself is not erroring.

NOTE: There were 103 observations read from the data set WORK.DUMMY_2.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds

but the data it's showing in the results tab when I do the quick print for the new group variable is giving me  a single column of bmi data except everything is (.)

There is no other group variable in the file (I search the excel version I have saved)

I then changed the variable name to condition thinking that the name group may be too similar to a command. 
Inline image 1

it now says condition instead of group on the top of the column, but I'm not sure why it's bringing up these chart.

```
data dummy_2;
set dummy;
if ptID = 'condition' then condition=0;
if ptID = 102-545 or ptID= 800-810 then condition =0;
if ptID = 600-632 then condition=1;
if ptID = 700-721 then condition=2;
if ptID = 99999 or 99998 then condition=.;
run;

proc print; 
var condition;
run;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try adding `FORMAT condition 1.;`. Also is your ptID variable numerical? You can check using `PROC CONTENTS DATA=dummy;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ptID = 600-632 then condition=1;
```

What do you think that does?

I'll give you a clue.  It's identical to this.

```
if ptID = -32 then condition=1;
```

I'm going to guess that isn't what you were hoping for.  You need to use the `in` operator.

```
if ptID  in (600:632) then condition=1;
```

I'm assuming `ptID` is numeric.  If it's character then you can't quite do this, and you should let us know.

I would note that the best way to do this sort of grouping is with a format:

```
proc format;
  value condGroupF
    102-545 = '0'
    600-632 = '1'
    700-721 = '2'
    800-810 = '0'
    99998-99999 = ' '
    other= ' '
  ;
quit;
```

And then

```
data dummy_2;
  set dummy;
  condition = put(ptID,CondGroupF.);
run;
```

Note in formats, the 'dash' style is correct, it's in the data step that it's not.

Comment: Not seen the colon (`:`) used that way before, nice.